# Stuck or sticking joystick on Raspberry Pi based mame emulator

Tags: keyboard, raspberry-pi, emulation

I'm posting this up as I spent ages looking for a solution and nothing was clearly documented. Hopefully this post will save someone else the hassle I've been through.

I recently built a Raspberry Pi based arcade machine. Using proper arcade controllers through an iPac-2 interface (which is essentially a glorified keyboard).

The joysticks were occasionally sticking in a particular direction (not physically, but as far as the games were concerned). This was obviously a problem when playing games.

Turns out the issue was that the keyboard (the iPac-2) wasn't getting enough power through the USB ports.

Editing /boot/config.txt and adding max_usb_current=1 to the end of the file solved this problem. Just make sure that you're using a decent power supply for the Pi in the first place.

Comment: If you wish to answer your own question you need to first write the question, and then on the bottom you can choose answer your own question.

Comment: You should edit the question so that only the question part of it is present. Then post an answer of your own and accept it.

Comment: Also you should consider posting this on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com instead of here.